# Textchanged Event and button click event small talk

Tags: c#, events

When you set a "textbox_texchanged" event with conditions like for example:

```
if (textbox.Text != "")
                {
                    //do something..
                }
                else
                {
                    //do this instead..
                }
```

and you have a search button. The textchanged code supposedly should work as long as the condition is met right? But I get confused that when the values changes while condition is still met, sometimes the textbox_Textchanged event does not occur. So my question is, how much does the button search click affect textchanged if it does or am i just a confused newbie at programming(Which I really am. Literally)?

Comment: The button Click event doesn't raise the TextChanged event on the textbox unless, if you raise the Click event and change the text on  the textbox.

Comment: @zer09 Good point. How about if the textbox was used in a computation like if textbox1 & textbox2 is = something then textbox3 is = this. What are your opinions about it? Thanks for responding. :)

Comment: @P.Pat using the values in a text box will not effect the values in them.  BUT if you are asking "will adding the vaues of two textboxes, and then setting the value of a third textbox equal to the resulting sum, trigger the TextChanged event of the third textbox?" the answer is YES.

Comment: @P.Pat As long as it is only subscribed to textbox3, only textbox3 can raise that event. Have a look on this msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: @Lodestone6 Cool. Not I'm not confused anymore on how it works. Thanks for responding!

Comment: @zer09 really helpful. thanks!